# Apply CSS class to multiple objects

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply a css class to all `<th class='euroth'></th>` which are located in either `table.tablesorter-All-Activity` or `table.tablesorter-Events`.

This is what I did

```
table.tablesorter-All-Activity,.tablesorter-Events th.euroth {
    width: 7px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 5;
    }
```

As a result, the first table is shifted all the way to the left and the second one accepts the style nicely.

Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: a comma indicates separate elements that the styles will be applied to. You need to enter `th.euroth` twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to append `th.euroth` to your first selector:

```css
.tablesorter-All-Activity th.euroth,
.tablesorter-Events th.euroth {
    /* properties go here... */
}
```